# ArrayList<String> in Reverse

Tags: java, arraylist, reverse

Im having problems because the ArrayList coins is located in the class Purse but I need it in the tester class to print out the Reverse. Im not sure if I need to make a new ArrayList in the tester class that copies the other or something totally different. Any answers are of help!
Thanks!

```
    package edu.purse.test;

   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.Collections;

    public class Purse 
   {
         ArrayList<String> coins = new ArrayList<String>();
         public Purse()
   {

   }
    public void addCoin(String coinName)
    {

    coins.add(coinName);
     }
public String toString()
{
    return  "Purse" + coins.toString();
}
public ArrayList<String> getReversed(ArrayList<String> coins) 
{ 
ArrayList<String> copy = new ArrayList<String>(coins); 
Collections.reverse(copy); 
return copy; 
}

    }

package edu.purse.test;

 import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class PurseTester {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Purse p = new Purse();
    p.addCoin("Quarter");
    p.addCoin("Dime");
    p.addCoin("Nickel");
    p.addCoin("Penny");
    System.out.println(p.toString());

    System.out.println(getReversed(coins));
}
```

}

Comment: I figured it out. I didn't need to send anything in the parameter of getReversed()

Answer (score 0):

Add a getter to the Purse class:

`public ArrayList<String> getCoins() {`
`return coins;`
`}`

... and then use the p.getCoins() in your tester class